# How to simplify this code snippet in java?

Tags: java, android

I have a part of ugly code snippet:

```
if (name.equals("video"))
    getString(R.string.video);
else if (name.equals("music"))
    getString(R.string.music)
else if (name.equals("picture"))
    getString(R.string.picture);
else if (name.equals("text"))
    getString(R.string.text);
else if (name.equals("apk"))
    getString(R.string.apk);
```

is it possible to be simplified to something like `getString(R.string.#{ name })`

Comment: Show more code. If you are using Java 7 you can use a switch-case statement instead.

Comment: @MarounMaroun sorry, it is java 6, but Java 7 can do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about codereview and should be ask at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: if you are useing Java 6, you can use Enums to switch-case Strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the identifier by name:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", getPackageName());
String str = getResources().getString(id);
```

---

<strike>Only problem:</strike>

```
else if (name.equals("text"))
    getString(R.string.picture);
```

You could make an if statement before getting the identifier to check this.

Comment: sorry, that is my mistake

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `Map<String, String>` populated similar to

```
Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<String, String>();
MAP.put("video", R.string.video);
MAP.put("music", R.string.music);
// ...and so on

if (MAP.containsKey(name)) {
    getString(MAP.get(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection api, something like this

```
Field f = R.string.getClass().getDeclaredField("text");
getString(f.get(String.class));
```